# Webpage Connection

Tags: javascript, html, dns, subdomain

I am trying to connect my subdomain (https://www.subdomain.webpage.com) to an external javascript page (x.x.x.x/DIBS_X_X/pages.jsp) through DNS records, is this viable? The third party gave me the IP address seen through the javascript page but it doesn’t connect because the IP address can’t be reached without the (/DIBS_X_X/pages.jsp). Would a CNAME record be enough to connect to point to this page? How would someone usually go about to connect to an external javascript page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what's happening here to understand why what you're trying to do won't work.

Hostnames, like `www.subdomain.webpage.com` resolve to network address.  When you try to go to `https://example.com/some-page`, first `example.com` is looked up at the configured DNS server, which might resolve that hostname to `192.0.2.1`.

Next, a network connection is made between the computer running the browser and the server at `192.0.2.1`.  As this is HTTPS, a TLS session is started over this connection, to encrypt traffic between the browser and the server.

Now, the browser asks the server for the page:

```
GET /some-page
```

Note that this has *nothing* to do with the hostname.  (Yes, it's true that there is usually a `Host:` header here, to allow the server to use multiple hostnames on one server, but that isn't relevant.  By now, we're already connected to a specific server.)

At the DNS layer of all this, you can only point your hostname at some IP address.  That's it.